# Which is a better js coding practice?

Tags: javascript

I need to send api calls to get data from multiple sources.The data that I get are in different format (arrays, objects,nested arrays). One thing I feel good about is to have an function that extract the parts I need from for me.

Now I wonder if I should have this extraction function or simply just extract the data I need when I use it.(Simply put : which one is a better practice?)

I personally prefer the latter one because I will not need to go back and forth to make sure which part of data I need to extract.
Eg.

Inline extraction

```
const  data = get("example.com").data[0].Users;
```

Use function to extract data

```
const data = getData("example.com";

const getData = async(url)=>{
   const rawData= await get(url);
   switch(url){
    case EXAMPLE_URL:
      return rawData.data[0].Users;
    case OTHER_EXAMPLE_URL:
      return rawData.data;
    case  OTHER_URL:
     return rawData.data[0].Enum;

}
}
```

Comment: I mean, if you have to do it over and over again, then a function is good, but this function you wrote is super tightly coupled and crazy brittle.  Your better off with 3 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split that into multiple functions. Imo, the caller should not need to know what url to pass to get some distinct value.

And you don't know whether you'll end up with fetching two different values from the same url.

```
//maybe using a simple utility
const getUrlPath = (url, ...path) => {
  let fetchPath = path.reduceRight((next, key) => obj => next(obj[key]), identity);
  return () => get(url).then(fetchPath);
}
const identity = v => v;    

//and then creating the different functions to get the different values
const getExample = getUrlPath(EXAMPLE_URL, "data", 0, "Users");
const getOther = getUrlPath(OTHER_EXAMPLE_URL, "data");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

One core idea you should aim to is **a function should only do one thing, but be very darn good at it**, so don't aim for 'one func to rule them all.' solution.

In your case, you're looking for three things in two task, fetching from url, and extract data from result. I suggest you create function for those

```
// Task 1: Fetch URL
const fetchUrl = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('example.com', { ...some options });

  // Do some error checking (just demo code for idea)
  if (response.status === 'error') throw new Error('fethcing Error Message');

  // If no error found, return with response
  return response;
}


// Task 2: extract data
const getUserFromResponse = response => response.data[0].Users;

const getEnumFromResponse = response => response.data[0].Enum;
```

Now you can compose those into your working functions.

```
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetchUrl();
    const user = getUserFromResponse(response);
    return user;
  } catch (e) {
     // do error handling
  }
}

const getEnum = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetchUrl();
    const enum = getEnumFromResponse(response);
    return enum;
  } catch (e) {
     // do error handling
  }
}
```

Breaking functions down to a single task will make it easier to create a test case and force you into write more reusable codes too, hope this helps, cheers :)